# get_called_class() $this object

Tags: php, polymorphism

How to I get the object `$this` of that class where the current function was called from?

```
class a extends zebra {
  function xyz() {
     ...
     b::somestaticmethod();
  }
}

class b {
  public static function somestaticmethod() {
    $callerObj = get_called_class();
  }
}
```

The function `get_called_class()` fetches the name of the calling class in string format. What I am looking for is that, is there a way to get the object (`$this`) from the context of the calling class, just like what would have happened if `$this` was passed as an argument as below.

```
b::somestaticmethod($this);
```

**Why?**

I am planning to implement a polymorphic behavior on the `somestaticmethod()` method, which will check the calling class and based on the `ancestor` of that class guide the logic further.

Comment: To clarify, you don't want just the class name but the actual object of the called class?

Comment: Yup thats **exactly** what I am looking for. ....The whole object with all the inheritance and everything, without actually passing it as an argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a thing exists however, why don't you just pass `$this` as a parameter?

Comment: Yeah I have currently implemented it as you are suggesting, but then I was looking for a way to independently get the object without the need to pass the object, which (passing the object manually) doesn't give me a concrete guarantee that exactly `$this` was passed and not some other object. Just like the analogy of why use `get_called_class()` when you can just pass the class name from the calling class :) hope you get my point.

Comment: This is the only other thing I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093101/php-classes-get-access-to-the-calling-instance-from-the-called-method - and they all seem to be passing parameters from what I could tell from a quick glance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5

Comment: Thanks peeps, im gonna go through these resources real quick :)

Comment: @MrGlass does that return the calling object? That is the key part of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection seems to work with inheritance and static class properties

```
<?php

class a {
  public static function x() {
    $callerObj = get_called_class();
    return new ReflectionClass($callerObj); 
  }
}

class b extends a {
    public static $y = [0, 1, 2];

    public static function z() {
        return parent::x()->getProperty('y')->getValue();
    }
}

print_r(b::z());
array_push(b::$y, 3);
print_r(b::z());
```